# Turn off the v0.1 and v1beta1 endpoints via GCP console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Flutter + Firebase app, and received an email about "Legacy GAE and GCF Metadata Server endpoints will be turned down on April 30, 2020". I updated it to v1 or whatever, and at the end of the email it suggests to turn off the endpoints completely. I'm using Google Cloud Functions and the email says

```
If you are using App Engine Standard or Cloud Functions, set the following environment variable: DISABLE_LEGACY_METADATA_SERVER_ENDPOINTS=true.
```

Upon further research this can be done through the console (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#custom). It says to add it as custom metadata (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#disable-legacy-endpoints) but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

For additional info, the email was triggered from a few cloud functions I have where I used the firebase admin to send push notifications (via cloud messaging)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#custom) feature you mention is meant to be used with Compute Engine and allows to pass in arbitrary values to your project or instance, and set startup and shutdown scripts. It's a handy way to pass common environment variables to all your GCE VMs in your project. You can also use those custom metadata in [App Engine Flexible instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#metadata_server) because they are actually Compute Engine VMs in your project running your App Engine code.

Cloud Functions and App Engine Standard are fundamentally different in that they don't run in your project but in a Google-owned project. This makes your project-wide custom metadata unreachable to them.

For this reason, for Cloud Functions you'll need to set a [CF-specific environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) by either:

- using the `--set-env-vars` flag when deploying your Function with the `gcloud functions deploy` command
- adding it to the environment variable section of your Function when [creating it via the Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add)